Substantial differences between Custom and Express, leaving aside the Express dashboard
I have been doing a bit of a study on Stripe's Connect technology. In particular, I focused more on the difference between the Custom and Express account. I realised how the Express account represents a sort of middle ground between the Standard and Custom account, thus providing a lightweight dashboard from which the user can access to view transactions, as well as updates to personal information. Now, I have also discovered that a Connect onboarding is provided for both the Express and Custom accounts, and the following question immediately arises: what would really be the substantial differences between the two types of accounts (Express and Custom), apart from the Connect onboarding and the Express dashboard provided by the Express account? Both can be interacted with programmatically to tailor the payment logic to our purposes.
I have searched for a long time for substantial differences but cannot really grasp them. At the moment, the only difference I have found might be related to the updating of personal and legal information, due to the requirements to be fulfilled. In this case, the Express dashboard offers the possibility to edit as opposed to Custom, which instead has to be made ad hoc.
Is there some detail I am missing??

I think Stripe Support - https://support.stripe.com/contact will be able to advise you on this!
